# How to pass const variable to the event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just starting to learn ReactJS.This is going to be a public transportation web app. I'm just starting to figuring out how the connections between the different component are working.

How is it possible to pass the `dataOne` and `dataTwo` variables - which are the names of the stations - to the onClick event handler, so that I can use them on the `StationOne` component?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import StationOne from '../components/station-one.component'

const HomePage = () => {
  const geoSucess = (loca) => {
    let lat = loca.coords.latitude
    let long = loca.coords.longitude

    const url = `http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/locations?limit=2&x=${lat}&y=${long}`
    fetch(url)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => fetchApi(data))
  }

  const geoError = (erro) => {
    console.log(erro, 'Something went wrong')
  }

  window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSucess, geoError)

  const fetchApi = (data) => {
    const yourAdress = document.getElementById('yourAdress')
    deineAdresse.innerHTML = data.stations[0].name

    const nameStationOne = document.getElementById('.nameStationOne')
    const dataOne = data.stations[1].name
    nameStationEins.innerHTML = dataOne

    const nameStationTwo = document.getElementById('.nameStationTwo')
    const dataTwo = data.stations[2].name
    nameStationZwei.innerHTML = dataTwo

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Your Location:</h1>
      <h3 id='yourAdress'></h3>
      <h2>Stations near your location:</h2>
      <Link to='/first-connection' onClick={StationOne}>
        <h3 id='nameStationEins'></h3>
      </Link>
      <h3 id='nameStationTwo'></h3>
      <br />
      <Link to='/second-connection' onClick={StationOne}>
        <h3 id='nameStationTwo'></h3>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
export default HomePage
```

In the `StationOne` component I'm going to use them as a variable. So that I can put them in a new fetch to search for next connections.

Comment: How does you station one look like. Usually you pass parameters to a component as props.

Comment: Clicking on those `<Link>`s will change the route of the app; the respective components are rendered by a `<Route>` element, which supports URL params. So you could do `<Route path="/first-connection/:station" render={props => <StationOne {...props} />}`. This way you can do `<Link to={'/first-connection/' + dataOne}>` and use `this.props.match.params.station` in the `StationOne` component to get the name of the station.

Comment: In general, sending data from one child to another works by passing the data up the tree (by setting the parent's state), then back down to the neighboring child as prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If station one is a function/handler you can do some like this...

```
 <Link to='/second-connection' onClick={() => StationOne(dataOne,dataTwo)}>
  <h3 id='nameStationTwo'></h3>
</Link>
```

But, looking at how you named it, I doubt it's an event handler. Again, how is StationOne defined. Usually you pass parameters to a component as props. Is StationOne a callback function/handler or a component. Also, you should look into the naming convention if you are planning with working on large teams. Usually the `PascalCase` is reserved for components and `camelCase` for callback. And from the looks of it, you using a component in place of a callback, its confusing.

The other confusing bit is that you are using an `onClick` handler on the `Link` from `react-router-dom`, [whose api](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) had no onClick prop.

If you wanted to use a component with Link, look at it's [`component`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/component-reactcomponent) prop.